# all my collada files import without textures

Tags: texturing, import

[image]

I downloaded characters from miximo but when I import them into blender they all seem to be dark without textures .and some nodes appear to be disconnected please help

Comment: Look at the Alpha socket on the Principled node. Is it 0? If you connect the Texture node's Alpha to it, do the textures work?

Comment: Thank you it worked